# signallAll method in threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading the book, "Core Java I" written by Cay H. Hostmann and he gives some information about the threads. He gives an example about threads and he gives a concrete banking example. As you know, in a bank, you may transfer funds, and he imagined that one fund transfer has implemented by one thread. At page 571 he wrote:

> If the transfer method finds that sufficient funds are not available, it calls
>
> "sufficientFunds.await();"
>
> The current thread is now deactivated and gives up the lock. This lets in another thread that can, we hope, increase the account balance.

> There is an essential difference between a thread that is waiting to acquire a lock and a thread that has called **await**. Once a thread calls the **await** method, it enters a wait set for that condition. The thread is not made runnable when the lock is available. Instead, it stays deactivated until another thread has called the **signalAll** method on the same condition. When another thread has transferred money, it should call

> sufficientFunds.signalAll();

> This call reactivates all
> threads waiting for the condition. When the threads are removed from the wait set, they are again runnable and the scheduler will eventually activate them again. At that time, they will attempt to
> **reenter the object**. As soon as the lock is available, one of them will acquire the lock and continue where it left off, **returning from the call to await.**

In the last paragraph, he mentioned: "reenter the object" (in bold). What does he mean? Also, he mentioned "returning from the call to await." Does he mean that the thread will start off from the point where **await** function calls?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By “re-enter the object” he means the threads will try to execute the methods on the object (that are protected by the lock).

And yes, at the point it is signaled the waiting thread is still executing the await method, it never went anywhere. The thread went into a wait state where it doesn’t get scheduled to run, getting signaled wakes it up, then it has to acquire the lock in order to leave the await method.

Comment: Thank you for the information. In the passage he says "There is an essential difference between a thread that is waiting to acquire a lock and a thread that has called await." What happens when a thread is waiting to acquire?

Comment: The thread trying to acquire the lock is still running, it’s just blocked. It still gets CPU time. Once the thread calls await it releases the lock (the one associated with the condition it called await on) and doesn’t do anything until it receives a signal from the condition. The scheduler takes the waiting thread off its list of threads it gives CPU time to.